# Puppet:Updating Integer to file content - Munging failed for value 0 in class content

Tags: puppet

I am trying to update the content with Integer 0. File resource below,

```
file { ['/sys/block/sda/queue/read_ahead_kb']: 
    content => 0,

}

Error : Failed to apply catalog: Parameter content failed on File[/sys/block/sda/queue/read_ahead_kb]: Munging failed for value 0 in class content: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String at /test/puppet/environments/mytest/modules/test/manifests/testdb/settings.pp:4
```

All i i need is to just have 0 in there ? I tried to have zero between quotes as string ,but it do not update the file and threw below errors.

Error 1:

```
Error: Could not back up /sys/block/sda/queue/read_ahead_kb: Got passed new contents for sum {md5}102e7bda3ff4572145809d25da2bbe11
```

I deleted /var/lib/puppet/clientbucket and re-ran the puppet.

Error 2:

```
Error:/Stage[main]/testdb::Settings/File[/sys/block/sda/queue/read_ahead_kb]/content: change from {md5}102e7bda3ff4572145809d25da2bbe11 to {md5}cfcd208495d565ef66e7dff9f98764da failed: Operation not permitted @ dir_s_mkdir - /sys/block/sda/queue/read_ahead_kb20200315-47213-5b01k6.lock
```

Can anybody help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect you can't use a `file` resource to manage the special files in `/sys`. `/sys` may look like a directory of files, but it really isn't.

There are Puppet modules available to manage `/sys` settings. For example, https://forge.puppet.com/danfoster/sysfs, which would allow you to use something like

```
include sysfs

sysfs::setting { 'class/block/sda/queue/read_ahead_kb':
  value => 0
}
```